# Why doesn't if variable ~= "text" work in lua 5.1/luajit?

Tags: arrays, string, lua

Complete newb at Lua, my native is ASM.  I'm parsing a text file searching for a particular string in a line of text (referenced in table) and writing a new file as I go line by line.  Once the string is found and replaced, I'd like it to skip searching further to increase speed and just write every line to EOF.

This routine is multi-use so that a table of any number of lines can be used.

Most everything is irrelevant, just can't fathom why '**if pattern[x] ~= "STOP" then**' doesn't work.  The routine appears to either quit out or bypass the "v:bfind" code.  Maybe I'm missing something or should I be using string.match?

```
local uiBoot = "uiBoot.txt"
local uiBootpattern = {[[BlendTime F32(0.3000000119)]],
[[.BlendTime F32(0.1);]],
[[STOP]],
}

function cb_fastmenu(file,pattern)
    local fastmenu = function(pattern)
    local x = 1
    local k,v
    for k,v in ipairs(bs_old) do
        if pattern[x] ~= "STOP" then <--------Doesn't work
            if v:bfind(sprot2(pattern[x])) then
                bs_old[k] = pattern[x+1]
                x = x+2
            end
        end
        add(v) --add line to file
    end
    end
    cb_add(fastmenu,{pattern},file,true,true)
end
```

Any help greatly appreciated.  I'll probably facepalm when someone explains.  Hopefully there's a way to optimize the lot as well.

Comment: Insert `print(pattern[x])` before `if pattern[x] ~= "STOP"` and see.

Comment: Thanks @Alexander. Weird stuff happening. When I add `if pattern[x] ~= "STOP"`, then `bs_old[k] = pattern[x]` fails. I have to use `v = pattern[x]'. Somethings making variables inconsistent.

Comment: you only increment `x` when `v:bfind(sprot2(pattern[x]))` is true if it never is true `x` will never change from `1` and `pattern[x] ~= "STOP"` will never be true. your code provide is not a good [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), if you can create one you might solve your own problem or get a detail answer of what wrong here. we can only guess when we cant reproduce the error.

Comment: Good point @Nifim, but it's the nature of the beast that I KNOW a file contains what it does and somehow the routine avoids doing what it should and changes results in variables randomly as per my previous comment.  Doesn't make for easy bug-stomping.  However, in this case I managed to figure it out and used `pattern[x] ~= "STOP"` with `v = pattern[x]` where previously only `bs_old[k] = pattern[x]` would work, that is until I introduced the `STOP` check.